# How to deepcopy object which contains pygame.Surface?

Tags: python, pygame, deep-copy

I'm writing a 2D game engine in pygame and I'm kind of stuck writing spawner class.
What i want to achieve is a simple way of creating spawner, like:

```
bullet = Bullet()
spawner = Spawner()
spawner.set_spawn_object(bullet)
```

Im using copy.deepcopy inside set_spawn_object

Basically I want to pass an object to spawner and it should deepcopy that object and hold that copy. Then every n seconds it will spawn that object by copying it to the global list of game objects which are rendered collided etc. I need a deepcopy because i want to modify them later individually (for example position, name, texture). The issue is that surfaces cannot be copied this way.

Right now each object in my game engine has its own surface, what I planned to do is to hold all surfaces in one separated class to make it more efficient. That could solve that issue, because I wouldn't copy surfaces. But...

Lets say i have a **bullet** and a **resource_manager** objects.
bullet has a pointer to a **resource_manager.bullet_texture** (it's a **pygame.Surface**).

Then I could
`bullet2=copy.deepcopy(bullet)`
because I'd be copying pointer, not the surface itself.

The problem is python doesnt have pointers, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `copy` module on a `pygame.Surface`, but `Surface` has its own [Surface.copy](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) method.

You can define a `copy` method for your classes which create a new instance with copies of all the needed attributes, using the `Surface.copy` method for the Surface instances.

If you have a lot of attributes, you may use the special built-in attribute `__dict__`: it holds a dictionary of attributes (keys) and their values, you can loop over it to assing to each attribute a copy of the original.

A very simple example:

```
class Myobject:
    def __init__(self, image=None, rect=None):
        self.image = image #a pygame surface
        self.rect = rect #a rectangle
        self.level = 0

    def copy(self):
        copyobj = Myobject()
        for name, attr in self.__dict__.items():
            if hasattr(attr, 'copy') and callable(getattr(attr, 'copy')):
                copyobj.__dict__[name] = attr.copy()
            else:
                copyobj.__dict__[name] = copy.deepcopy(attr)
        return copyobj
```

now if you do:

```
myobj = Myobject(an_image, a_rectange)
myobj2 = myobj.copy()
```

`myobj2` is a "copy" of `myobj`. Its image and rect are different instances which have the same values, and you can safely edit the latter and the former remains unaltered.

So, if you want to create a spawner, the spawner might call the `copy` method of the passed object.

```
class Spawner:
    @staticmethod
    def set_spawn_object(obj):
        return obj.copy()
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the class has number of variables and I can't just manually copy everything. Also i have many classes that inherit from it and add more variables. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, if you do `newsurface = oldsurface`, then `newsurface` is a reference to the same surface referred by `oldsurface`. They point to the same object.

Comment: So I can use regular copy on surface and deepcopy on other things. Can I somehow iterate through all class variables and check whether or not current one is a surface and decide which copy to use? How to achieve it?

Comment: If you can use different methods on the attributes, then I would use `Surface.copy()` to get a copy of the Surface, and deepcopy for the non-pygame things. But if you can split, I still suggest to go for the `copy` method as I mentioned in my answer. You can always use `deepcopy` inside the class `copy` method.

Comment: Sorry, I've read it now. Yes, you can iterate through the class attributes. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Please do :) I can't find how to iterate through all variables. All I found was vars() function but it returns a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much :D I get it now

Comment: I've made some fix, I realized there was an error. Now should be correct.

Comment: Well It doesn't work yet. Still ends up trying to deepcopy a surface. I'm also trying to figure it out. But the thing with dict looks like a good approach :)

Comment: this kind of detection looks like its working - I'll work on it more
`try:
    getattr(getattr(self, attr), 'copy'):
        print('copy method exists')
    except:
        print('no such thing')`

Comment: Fixed now. Using `items()` to iterate over the dict makes things a little more clear